# Include css file in Orchard

Tags: .net, css, layout, orchardcms, shapes

I created a new theme (MyTheme) that was inherited from TheThemeMachine by using Codegen tool. 
In Layout.cshtml of MyTheme, I included some CSS files as global CSS (Style.Include(...)).
Then, I created a shape named Register in order to render a register form. In (MyArea)/Views/Register.cshtml file, I used Style.Include("register.css") to include the register.css file. But when the Register shape was rendered in Chrome, I found that the register.css file was located before css files which I included in Layout.cshtml ?!! So, the register form didn't display what I want.
In my opinion, the register.css must be located after the global css files which I included in Layout.cshtml, because the register.css was included in Content in Layout ! But the real showed that is'nt!
Can you help me explain why it is and what I should do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Why does it matter what order your css files are getting rendered in? Does one depend on the other?

Comment: Surely @BertrandLeRoy ! My register.css file depends on one of the css files in Layout.cshtml. Therefore, if the order my css files is incorrect, my register page will be rendered incorrectly :). What should I do ?

Comment: this is an issue that has already been reported as a bug in Orchard. I'm not sure of the status of it though. I think it was to do with whether you used _Include_ or _Require_. This also happens with scripts in exactly the same fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you have the following setup:

- global.css in your theme
- register.css in your module

Now you want register.css after global.css since the former depends on the latter.

You can hack this together but the real issue is with your dependency chain. Themes have the highest priority regarding styling, so stylesheets and scripts will be included from them last (if no explicit dependency is defined in a resource manifest for them) and their shape overrides will take precedence over overrides in modules. The idea behind this is, that you should be able to override anything from a theme.

That said your register.css shouldn't depend on global.css. A module is a stand-alone sub-application that should take care of containing or requiring anything it needs. If you don't want to include such styling in your modules then just include register.css in your theme (like global.css).